# Injecting Touch on Coordinates via Key

Tags: android, mobile, keyboard, game-development

is there a way to put an app into background which fulfills the solely purpose of re-binding Keys from an Keyboard (In actual case Tosh AC100 Smartbook) with a certain defined X-Y Coordinate to simulate a touch on that spot?

Background is: In this state of Android game developement, only a few companies support hardkey-input in their games. With this injection of input, even all-touch based games would be playable.

Thanks for reading & your time!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, but only if you have root access. Then you can inject events by directly writing to /dev/input/eventX .